# p-columnFilter is not a known element

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have also included the TableModule in my module file but still getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9faP.png) error

Answer (score 3):

ColumnFilter is a new component. You need to use Angular 11, PrimeNg11, and import into app.module file.